# C and C++: Freeing PART of an allocated pointer

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

Let's say I have a pointer allocated to hold 4096 bytes.  How would one deallocate the last 1024 bytes in C?  What about in C++?  What if, instead, I wanted to deallocate the *first* 1024 bytes, and keep the rest (in both languages)?  What about deallocating from the middle (it seems to me that this would require splitting it into two pointers, before and after the deallocated region).

Comment: not sure about it but using "fake" pointer with right size, deleting or freeing the one you want should do the trick, need at least 2 pointers.

Comment: @claferri. That's undefined behaviour. You can only free() pointers returned from malloc/realloc - otherwise, how does free() know how much to free?

Comment: @roddy : oups you're right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `n` bytes of `malloc`ated memory, you can `realloc` `m` bytes (where `m` < `n`) and thus throw away the last `n-m` bytes.

To throw away from the beginning, you can `malloc` a new, smaller buffer and `memcpy` the bytes you want and then `free` the original.

The latter option is also available using C++ `new` and `delete`. It can also emulate the first `realloc` case.

Comment: "malloc/memcpy/free" is how realloc may be implemented internally.

Comment: I agree that realloc will usually return the (same) first part, but is it an official requirement for realloc? I think here might be implementations that could move the data to a new spot.

Comment: Imagine an intelligent reallocation scheme wherein the historical pattern of allocations is tracked... if there had been recent allocation requests for 4096 bytes, it might be better to move the shrinking block elsewhere to free up this 4K block. In which case the address will change. And realloc returns a pointer to the new memory area, so the programmer should use it. Whether it changes or not.

Comment: an alternate way to throw away the beginning would be to use `memmove()` to move the data back, then `realloc()` to required size

Answer (score 12):

Don't try and second-guess memory management. It's usually cleverer than you ;-)

The only thing you can achieve is the first scenario  to 'deallocate' the last 1K

```
char * foo = malloc(4096);

foo = realloc(foo, 4096-1024);
```

However, even in this case, there is NO GUARANTEE that "foo" will be unchanged. Your entire 4K may be freed, and realloc() may move your memory elsewhere, thus invalidating any pointers to it that you may hold.

This is valid for both C and C++ - however, use of malloc() in C++ is a bad code smell, and most folk would expect you to use *new()* to allocate storage. And memory allocated with new() cannot be realloc()ed - or at least, not in any kind of portable way. STL vectors would be a much better approach in C++

Answer (score 5):

You don't have "a pointer allocated to hold 4096 bytes", you have a pointer to an allocated block of 4096 bytes.

If your block was allocated with `malloc()`, `realloc()` will allow you to reduce or increase the size of the block. The start address of the block won't necessarily stay the same, though.

You can't change the start address of a `malloc`'d memory block, which is really what your second scenario is asking. There's also no way to split a `malloc`'d block.

This is a limitation of the `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`/`free` API -- and implementations may rely on these limitations (for example, keeping bookkeeping information about the allocation immediately before the start address, which would make moving the start address difficult.)

Now, `malloc` isn't the only allocator out there -- your platform or libraries might provide other ones, or you could write your own (which gets memory from the system via `malloc`, `mmap`, `VirtualAlloc` or some other mechanism) and then hands it out to your program in whatever fashion you desire.

For C++, if you allocate memory with `std::malloc`, the information above applies. If you're using `new` and `delete`, you're allocating storage for and constructing objects, and so changing the size of an allocated block doesn't make sense -- objects in C++ are a fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it shorter with realloc(). I don't think the rest is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use realloc() to apparently make the memory shorter. Note that for some implementations such a call will actually do nothing. You can't free the first bit of the block and retain the last bit.

If you find yourself needing this kind of functionality, you should consider using a more complex data structure. An array is not the correct answer to every programming problem.

Comment: I'm implementing a memory system, so I'm looking to get as low-level of access as I can while still remaining portable.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)

> SUMMARY:In contrast to C's realloc, it
>   is not possible to directly reallocate
>   memory allocated with new[]. To extend
>   or reduce the size of a block, one
>   must allocate a new block of adequate
>   size, copy over the old memory, and
>   delete the old block. The C++ standard
>   library provides a dynamic array that
>   can be extended or reduced in its
>   std::vector template.